# Android: App unable to access network(java.net.UnknownHostException) even when device is connected

Tags: android, networking, tcp

I'm developing an Android chat app based on Xmpp. I am stuck in this weird situation where my app is unable to access internet, even when other apps on the phone can connect to internet. This situation happens after a period of inactivity, otherwise the app connects to internet just fine. So I assume the permissions in the manifest file are correct.

These are the steps I use to reproduce this situation.

1. Start app - App connects to internet perfectly.
2. After a few minutes of inactivity, app gets disconnected - apparently the Xmpp TCP connection times out.
3. I send a GCM(Firebase) message to wake up the App and try to get it to connect back to internet. GCM notification gets displayed just fine.
4. But App is unable to connect to internet and I get the following error

   `The following addresses failed: 'dev.xxx.com:5222' failed because java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "dev.xxx.com": No address associated with hostname`

Two observations at this stage:

1. Other apps can connect to internet while my app keeps complaining about `UnknownHostException`
2. Manually re-launching the app by clicking on the icon, allows the app to reconnect to internet.

Any pointers as to why this is happening? I'm using a Xiaomi phone for testing the app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you downloading anything in onMessageRecived, it could be something like an image

Btw if you are using Firebase it's called FCM